# Mysql views need to limit function

Tags: mysql, function, view, limit

Mysql views need to limit function.

I can't get records with this query.

```
SELECT * from `options_views`
```

But this query works fine

```
SELECT * from `options_views` LIMIT 0, 30
```

I'm using laravel 5 and I need to get all records from the database...

I'm need to work with Mysql Views.

You have any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by _"can't get records"_ - do you get an error, if so what is it.

Comment: No, server is getting busy after that `SELECT * from options_views` And can't answer to me anymore. If I run this query with `limit 0,30` clause I can get 30 results. ~10.000 Records in database.

I can get all results in the **table** with this query `SELECT * from  a_table`

I can't get **any** results in the **views** with this query `SELECT * from options_views`

Comment: Sounds like the view is getting a very large number of records & taking a long time to do it. The view will need to be optimised if you really do need to get the full set of results.

Comment: Can you give some more information about the database & also the view that you are using.

Comment: Hmm, I have big database. 

This database table structure like;
 
hotels
rooms
room_price
rooms_options
room_images
hotel_images
etc.

I'm using Laravel 5 Eloquent.

And I need to multidimensional mysql query; I tryed join like query structure. But like this code is very very slow. Need to convert price or need to image for room. I want to join tables and I'm searching fast solution. What is your proposal.

Comment: Without seeing the view query then there is no way to give you any help beyond saying it needs optimising.

Answer (score 0):

This is my view query.

room_price: 9786 records

room_quota: 11042 records

rooms : 50 records

```
CREATE VIEW odalar_view
AS SELECT 
rooms.ID, rooms.OTELID,

room_price.KISIFIYATC,room_price.ODAFIYATC,room_price.DOVIZ,

room_quota.KONTENJAN,

rooms.ODAADI,rooms.SLIDE, rooms.ODAID, rooms.YETISKINSAYISI, rooms.COCUKSAYISI , rooms.ODAACIKLAMA, rooms.ODAOZELLIKLER , 

rooms.ODABUYUKLUGU , rooms.YATAKBUYUKLUGU , rooms.ODAADEDI , rooms.KONAKLAMATIPI, rooms.TEKKISILIKYATAKSAY, rooms.CIFTKISILIKYATAKSAY , 

rooms.BUYUKIKIKISILIKYATAKSAY , rooms.EXBUYUKIKIKISILIKYATAKSAY , rooms.RANZASAY , rooms.CEKYATSAY , rooms.SILTESAY,

FROM room_price,
room_quota,
rooms
```

Comment: Note - this would have been better added as an edit to the original question rather than added as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified any join conditions for the three tables, so your query will return 9786 * 11042 * 50 (= 5402850600) records. You need to correctly join the three tables.

If you need further help you will need to show the table schema.